Limit of integrals over compact $J$-measurale sets
Question. Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be an open $J$-measurable set and $(K_i)$ a sequence of compact $J$-measurable sets such that $K_i \subset \operatorname{int} K_{i+1}$ for every $i  \in \mathbb{N}$ and $U = \bigcup_{i} K_i$. Prove that, for every integrable function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$\int_{U} f(x) dx = \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} \int_{K_i} f(x) dx.$$
Initially, I thought it would be sufficient to observe that
$$\left|\int_{U} f(x) \, dx - \int_{K_i} f(x) \, dx \right| = \left|\int_{U-K_i} f(x) \, dx\right| \leq M \operatorname{vol}(U-K_i),$$
where $M$ denotes the maximum value of $f$ on $U$ (assuming $f$ is bounded, even though the exercise does not explicitly state this). We can see that as $\operatorname{vol}(U-K_i)$ approaches zero, the result would follow. However, this argument does not seem to take into account the compactness of $K_i$, the openness of $U$, or the condition $K_i \subset \operatorname{int}K_{i+1}$. How should I proceed?
EDIT: We also have a convergence result that allows us the pass the limit inside the integral when the sequence is uniformly convergent, so another approach would be to define $f_i = f\,\chi_{K_i}$ and integrate over $U$ for example. However, we would need to show that $f_i$ are integrable and that the convergence is uniform, which I'm not certain whether it is.

What is $J$? Does it mean Jordon?

@DannyPak-KeungChan Yes, Jordan measurable.

If you are working with Lebesgue integration theory, this follows from Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

We are working with Riemann integrals, not Lebesgue.

The multidimensional Riemann integral is only defined for bounded functions on bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The generalization analogous to the one-dimensional improper integral is sometimes called the extended integral and is defined for a nonnegative function over an open set $U$ as
$$\int_U f = \sup_E \int_E f,$$
where $E$ ranges over compact, Jordan measurable subsets of $U$.  For general functions, we define the integral using positive and negative parts, $f^+$ and $f^-$, according to
$$\int_Uf = \int_Uf^+ - \int_U f^-$$
To prove the theorem in question, first consider the case where $f$ is nonnegative and integrable on $U$ in the extended sense.
Since the sets $K_i$ are compact and subsets of $U$, we have
$\displaystyle\int_{K_i}f \leqslant \sup_E\int_Ef = \int_Uf.$ Hence,
$$\tag{1}\lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{K_i} f \leqslant \int_U f$$
On the other hand, if $E$ is any compact, Jordan measurable subset of $U$ then the collection $\{\text{int}K_i\}$ is an open cover of $E$.  Hence, $E$ is covered by finitely many sets in $\{\text{int} K_i\}$, and since $\text{int}K_i \subset \text{int} K_{i+1}$ there exists $n$ such that
$$\tag{2}\int _E f \leqslant \int_{K_n} f \leqslant \lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{K_i} f$$
Thus,
$$\tag{3}\int_U f = \sup_E \int_E f \leqslant \lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{K_i}f$$
Together, inequalities (1) and (3) show that
$$\tag{4}\lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{K_i} f= \int_U f$$
For a general function, result (4) holds for positive and negative parts, $f^+$ and $f^-$. It is then straightforward to extend (4) to general functions.
